# Laravel Session Token being changed on every refresh

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, laravel-5

Getting through these issues. Session is being stored correctly, the file isn't changing, and the session is still there. Session lifetime in the Config file is 120. However, my Session array _token key is changing the value on every single refresh so it's not able to pull the correct session that was written.

What might be causing the session token to change on every refresh on a page?

Session right after redirect on LoginController.php

```
array:7 [▼
"_token" => "7bcBy6cPKpMO0BBUvrVOUPd3YHmCSoMEpxHWLcvk"
"_previous" => array:1 [▶]
"flash" => array:2 [▶]
"login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc" => 78
"username" => "demo"
"Account" => "demo"
"Auth" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Session Array after first refresh:

```
array:1 [▼
"_token" => "o5l9uGjjmVwr5vZXC5MZH3GaClYXW1OxarWVN7p5"
]
```

Session Array after second refresh:

```
array:1 [▼
"_token" => "i5IFTEWM6txuNPSFL6SMa3a2gUrQzciREd8pUp4K"
]
```

As you can see the _token keeps changing and the rest of the session data is wiped. What might cause this?

**UPDATE:**
So I have now tested different session drivers. I've tested file, database, and cookie. All of them fail to keep the session data. What might be causing the session data to get wiped or not loaded correctly?

**UPDATE 2:**
So I've come across something very interesting. It's Chrome that's having the issue. When running this app in firefox, sessions are working fine. What would cause Chrome to be losing the session data?

Comment: have you tried disabling any extensions?

Comment: How is this `_token` generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was something like Arthur thought. It was to do with an old cookie session just overwriting the session constantly, even with cache being cleared and driver types being changed. After clearing my cookies for lifetime of chrome, it started writing correctly and keeping the session. This was a entirely new bug to me.

Comment: So how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The session token is stored (client side) via cookies. Check your chrome configuration.

go to:

```
chrome://settings/
```

Click on link:

```
show advanced settings...

Privacy > Content Setting...
```

By default the selected option is:

```
Allow local data to be set (recommended)
```

If local data is blocked, chrome will need a new authentication on every refresh, thus causing laravel to provide new tokens, just like you are experiencing.

Comment: It was something like this. It wasn't set to this, but there was for some reason old cookie data overwriting session every time no matter how I stored it. After clearing the cookie data it started writing correctly the cookies again. It's just odd that old cookie data would be overwriting the data even after clearing cache and changing the driver type.